# Omitting function arguments in PHP

Tags: php, function, parameters

I have a function that saves every user log that looks like this

```
<?php
function create_log($action=null, $outcome, $message)
  {
    require 'dbc.php';
    include 'get_ip.php';
    $ip = get_ip_address();
    $dateTime = date('m-d-Y h:i:s A', time());
    $query = "INSERT INTO tbllogs (logOrigin, logAction, logUser, logDate, logOutcome, logMessage) VALUES (:origin, :action, :user, :dt, :outcome, :message)";
    $stmt  = $dbc->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':origin', $ip);
    $stmt->bindParam(':action', $action);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $_SESSION['id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':dt', $dateTime);
    $stmt->bindParam(':outcome', $outcome);
    $stmt->bindParam(':message', $message);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
```

And when I call it I am doing it like this:

```
create_log('Log in', 'Failed', '');
```

My problem is, the $message parameter is only used whenever I need it only. Should I always call it like this `create_log('Log in', 'Failed', '');`or can I just call it like this? `create_log('Log in', 'Failed');`? If so, how?

Comment: Define function like function create_log($action=null, $outcome, $message = ''){} Then u can call create_log('Log in', 'Failed');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify [default values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) to the parameters:

```
function create_log($action = '', $outcome = '', $message = '')
```

This way, if you call `create_log` without one of the parameters, it will be assigned the value in the function's definition (`''` for all the parameters in the above example).